# Garbage when reading values from file in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to read values from a file called "CRIMES_Data.csv". I tried printing the values read and got garbage. I put in a check to see where the problem is arising and turns out it is not reading values from the file at all.

```
int i, j, RAW_DATA[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("CRIMES_Data.csv", "r");
for (i=0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<MAX_COLS-1; j++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d,", &RAW_DATA[i][j]);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &RAW_DATA[i][j]);
}
```

Am I not opening the file correctly or is there a problem with the way I am trying to read the values? I am a newbie and have not used files previously.

The file has 31 Rows and 19 columns.
Example rows:

```
16,18,6,24,16,18,13,12,14,12,8,3,15,6,16,13,9,19,11  
6,7,8,10,14,13,8,8,5,12,4,4,8,6,6,7,6,6,7
```

I tried printing using

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_ROWS;i++){
    for(j=0; j<MAX_COLS;j++){
        printf("%d", RAW_DATA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

to ensure the values were read properly before I moved on to the next task.
Since it printed garbage, I set each value to 1 before the fscanf looping and that resulted in 1s being printed.

Another line of sample input (updated the correct number of rows and columns):

one example line of the garbage:

```
1027102743384832642021664202164338483243385024435158484338502443385024204743515856433848326420672433848322008298648435158560
```

But I have set the value of each element of the array to `1` prior to the `fscanf` part so the garbage is now just 31 lines of 19 `1`s.

Comment: Where is your `RAW_DATA` declaration? Have you checked that `fp != NULL`? What does part of `CRIMES_Data.csv` look like?

Comment: It is also worth looking at printing code where you get garbage. The error could be there.

Comment: My bet is `fp = fopen("CRIMES_Data.csv", "r");` is failing. `if (!fp) { perror ("CRIMES_Data.csv"); return 1; }`

Comment: More related to your problem, or rather your *question*, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit the question to improve it. Like for example show us some example contents of the file. And tell us more about how the code you show fails, and what you have tried to do to [debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be good as well.

Comment: To add to the suggestions about error checking, you should probably check what [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I have edited my question, I hope it is better suited to the forum's standard now.
@ David C.Rankin I added that to the code, still prints garbage (or the values i set the items to before the fscanf part)
@ Evert I have updated the question and my code. I hadnt checked if fp!=NULL, but I put david's code later.

Comment: Please show the garbage you get for the sampel input.

Comment: Please also show a pair of sample input and output for input with at least two lines.

Comment: Your sample row has 19 columns. That probably makes the expection of  `fscanf(fp, "%d\n"`... fail.

Comment: `MAX_COLS` == 18  and `MAX_ROWS`== 30?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i am using printf to check whether my values were read correctly (which fails because regardless of what I do, the code i wrote is simply not looking at the file). If you are pointing towards something else, can you please tell me how to check the return value of fscanf?

Comment: Try `printf("%d", RAW_DATA[i][j]);` ==> `printf("%d\t", RAW_DATA[i][j]);` first.

Comment: Is `fp` NULL when attempting the `fscanf()`? I.e. did you try Davids recommendation?

Comment: You need to use `if (fscanf(…) != 1)` then you have a problem. Note too that the scanning functions don’t care about newlines in the data. If you do (you probably should), you need to read lines with another function (`fgets()` for example) and scanf the line with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Are `MAX_COLS` == 19 and `MAX_ROWS`== 31?

Comment: @Yunnosch I checked the file again, it had somehow been reduced to nothing. I am not sure how since it had all the data before I started debugging. Sorry for being so clumsy.

Now I have another issue it is just reading the first line but I think I will be able to debug it myself

Comment: MAX_COLS == 18, MAX_ROWS==30.

Comment: @Yunnosch. I have changed max row and cols to 31 and 19 and now its working fine. Thank you

Comment: Just a quick suggestion; I'm actually pretty sure this is etiquette, but please don't edit in answers to your question; write an answer, instead. As a programming student, I have no doubt you will soon discover the value of this kind of structure, even on a subconscious level, though it would be far more firmly established if you studied search engine optimisation consciously...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is the newline not consumed by the single `fscanf(fp, "%d\n"...)`? According to OP it works now and the spec seems not to make a difference between whitespace, not even for newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause (as confirmend by OP) was a corrupted file, corrupted as in "empty".
this should be handled with error checking, as recommended by e.g. David, Some Programmer Dude and Jonathan.

I.e. add the following edits, in order to avoid similar problems in the future.

```
if (!fp)
{
     perror ("CRIMES_Data.csv"); return 1;
     /* not triggered by successfully opening an empty file though... */
}
```

and

```
read=fscanf(...);
/* do a plausibility check on the return value, e.g. that it is 1, the number of successfully read arguments */
```

Also handle the newlines, as recommended by Jonathan.

Also, with MAX_COLS == 18, this loop

```
for (j=0; j<MAX_COLS-1; j++)
```

will read 17 columns, another one is read after the loop, for a total of 18.
Your file is supposed to have 19 columns. After the single fscanf, the input stream will therefor be in a different state than you expect. (This, too, was confirmed by OP.)

Comment: I did add David's line of code but it did not produce an error. I am not well versed with using files in C so cannot say why that happened.

Comment: Opening an existing file will succeed and not cause the check proposed by David to trigger, even if it is empty. Reading something however fails then and does not write to the variables, which explains your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is correct but if it is all the code you wrote then you have to specify the value of `MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLS`.

Also since you are using a CSV file populate all the empty values with `NULL`.

```
int MAX_ROW = 31;
int MAX_COL = 19
```

Garbage is being generated because of the limit and empty values in the csv file.

Comment: Please explain the added value of this answer in comparison to the older, accepted and upvoted answer, which seems to contain all of your points (at least not already covered by info from OP, like initialising for better debugging) -
 and more.